# parameterized SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql, jena, apache-jena

I want to code a parameterized SPARQL Query in Java Jena where one of the triple in query be injected

so in the code below I need to inject value as a string the pass to the class

However, the SPARQL query is correct so when I replace "value" with the class name I got the right result

I tried two code non of them worked No result  or run time error

the first code:

```
package ontology;

import org.apache.jena.iri.impl.Main;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class SPARQL {
     public static void sparqlTest( String str)
     {
FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
Model model=FileManager.get().loadModel("ASO.owl");
    String queryString=

                "PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+ 
                "PREFIX rdf:< http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
                "PREFIX HASO:< http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>"+

                 "SELECT  ?x  "+

                 "WHERE"+ 

                 "      {?x rdfs:subClassOf  HASO:Affective_State}";


   ParameterizedSparqlString queryStr = new   ParameterizedSparqlString(queryString);
   queryStr.setLiteral("value", str);

   Query  query=QueryFactory.create(queryStr.toString());

   QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);

   try {
   ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();

   while ( results.hasNext()){
           QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
           String strg=soln.getResource("?x").toString();
           //System.out.println(strg);
             String number = strg.substring(strg.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
             System.out.println(number);

   }}

   finally{
   qexec.close();}

}
}
```

The Second code:

```
package ontology;

import org.apache.jena.iri.impl.Main;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class SPARQL {
public static void sparqlTest( String str)
     {

FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
Model model=FileManager.get().loadModel("ASO.owl");

   ParameterizedSparqlString pss = new ParameterizedSparqlString();
   pss.setCommandText (
                       "PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+ 

                       "PREFIX rdf:< http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+

                       "PREFIX HASO:< http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>"+


                 "SELECT  ?x  "+
                  "WHERE"+ 
    "      {?x rdfs:subClassOf  HASO:valuee}");
    pss.setLiteral("value", str);

   Query  query=QueryFactory.create(pss.toString());
   QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model);

   try {
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();

   while ( results.hasNext()){
           QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
           String strg=soln.getResource("?x").toString();
           //System.out.println(strg);
             String number = strg.substring(strg.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
             System.out.println(number);

   }}

  finally{

 qexec.close();}
 }
}
```

Comment: Already asked and answered on the Jena users mailing list.

Comment: I did not find answer to my Q in Jena users mailing list

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I didn't use SPARQL, but I don't see how you are actually injecting value parameter in your code. It should be something like this:

```
   pss.setCommandText (
        "PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+ 
        "PREFIX rdf:< http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
        "PREFIX HASO:< http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>"+


             "SELECT  ?x  "+
              "WHERE"+ 
                   "{?x HASO:value ?value}");
                    pss.setLiteral("value", str);
```

Maybe you will use some other predicate, but in order to inject value, you should have ?value in your query as object.

Comment: I tried the following , but with no result    

 pss.setCommandText (
    "PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+ 
    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
    "PREFIX HASO: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>"+
     
     
 "SELECT  ?x  "+
   "WHERE"+ 
 " {?x rdfs:subClassOf  ?value}");
 pss.setLiteral("value", "HASO:Affective_State");

 

Query  query=QueryFactory.create(pss.toString());

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to set resource as literal value. When you have triple {?person name ?namevalue} you will set namevalue as literal, and you should use pss.setLiteral("nameValue", "Bob"). If you have triple {?person rdfs:subClassOf ?entity} you should not set it as literal but as resource. It should be something like pss.setIni("entity","http://someurihere/Entity")

Comment: setIni is for ( string, iri) not ( string, string )   the next String will be passed by another class to the class that has SPARQL Query

Comment: what if I write the following ?
Node n= NodeFactory.createVariable("HASO:Affective_State");
 pss.setParam("value", n);
or
Node n= NodeFactory.createLiteral("HASO:Affective_State");

 pss.setParam("value", n);

Comment: ParameterizedSparqlString pss = new ParameterizedSparqlString();
 pss.setCommandText (
    
     
 "SELECT  ?x  "+
   "WHERE"+ 
 " {?x rdfs:subClassOf ?value}");
 
 pss.setNsPrefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");
    pss.setNsPrefix("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
 pss.setNsPrefix("HASO","http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#");
 
Node n= NodeFactory.createLiteral("HASO:Affective_State");


System.out.println(n);
 pss.setParam("value", n);
n= "HASO:Affective_State"
maybe this cause the error the " in n

Comment: setIri has 2 APIs one with IRI and one with String as second argument, so you can pass it as I suggested as string value. You can also pass Node using setParam method as you suggested, but you are again creating Literal instead. You should rather use NodeFactory.createURI in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using setLitral() is injecting String into query bounded by double quotes like:

```
String queryString
            = "PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"
            + "PREFIX HASO: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>"
            + "SELECT ?x WHERE {\n"
            + "  ?x rdfs:subClassOf ?clazz \n"
            + "}\n";

    ParameterizedSparqlString queryStr = new ParameterizedSparqlString(queryString);

    queryStr.setLiteral("clazz", "HASO:Affective_State");

    System.out.println(queryStr.toString());
```

The result of Query will be like:

```
PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX HASO: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>SELECT ?x WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:subClassOf "HASO:Affective_State" 
}
```

As you see above ?x rdfs:subClassOf "HASO:Affective_State"  where **"HASO:Affective_State"** . is wrong class name because it contains "" so no results will return if you execute that query.
**The SOLUTION**
Use String.format instead of ParameterizedSparqlString:: setLiteral:

```
String q
            = "PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"
            + "PREFIX HASO: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>"
            + "SELECT ?x WHERE {\n"
            + "  ?x rdfs:subClassOf %s \n"
            + "}\n"
            + "LIMIT %d";

    q = String.format(q, "HASO:Affective_State", 2);
    System.out.println(q);
```

The Result :

```
PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX HASO: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>SELECT ?x WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:subClassOf HASO:Affective_State 
}
LIMIT 2
```

As you see above HASO:Affective_State and 2 have been injected correctly, so you can inject as many params as you like using String.format [%s for string, %d for digit, and so on..]

Full Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JenaSystem.init();
    UpdateFactory.create();

    Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("ASO.owl");

    String q
            = "PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"
            + "PREFIX HASO: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#>"
            + "SELECT ?x WHERE {\n"
            + "  ?x rdfs:subClassOf %s \n"
            + "}\n"
            + "LIMIT %d";

    q = String.format(q, "HASO:Affective_State", 2);
    System.out.println(q);
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(q);
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    ResultSet resSet = qexec.execSelect();

    while (resSet.hasNext()) {

        QuerySolution soln = resSet.nextSolution();
        String strg = soln.getResource("?x").toString();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>> " + strg);
        String number = strg.substring(strg.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);
        System.out.println("<<<<<< " + number);

    }


}
```

Comment: zoran jeremic here the code with SetParam, but still no result

ParameterizedSparqlString pss = new ParameterizedSparqlString();
 pss.setCommandText (
    
     
 "SELECT  ?x  "+
   "WHERE"+ 
 " {?x rdfs:subClassOf ?value}");
 
 pss.setNsPrefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");
    pss.setNsPrefix("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
 pss.setNsPrefix("HASO","http://www.semanticweb.org/rabaa006/ontologies/2014/4/HASO#");
 
Node n= NodeFactory.createURI ("HASO:Affective_State");
System.out.println(n);
 pss.setParam("value", n);