# SPARQL query in Apache Jena

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I want to write a query similar to this --

```
select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o. ?s rdf:subClassOf + mySpecificSubjectValue +}
```

Is there any existing way to do this? Or Do I have to do it manually by checking all subjects. And also I don't want to use regex in query cause regex create some problems for example: base:hotel and base:hotelName

Comment: *"Is there any existing way to do this?"* -> May I ask you what you're asking for now? Did you read the documentation? I mean, it's just sending the query string, isn't it? You didn't show any code nor sample data. I hope you know that `mySpecificSubjectValue` must be a class?

Comment: *"Or Do I have to do it manually by checking all subjects."* - what does this question mean?

Comment: *"And also I don't want to use regex in query cause regex create some problems for example: base:hotel and base:hotelName"* - I don't see any regex in your query, again it's not clear what you're doing

Comment: By the way, it's called `rdfs:subClassOf`...

Comment: What I am trying express is: 
For example, I have this dataset

http://www.base.org/hotel rdfs:type base:hotel
http://www.base.org/hotel rdfs:label "something"
http://www.base.org/hotelArea rdfs:type base:hotelArea
http://www.base.org/hotelArea rdfs:label "something"

I want to extract all triples of hotel, not hotelArea. I don't want to use regex. I know the way of querying with regex. I am asking if there is a way to pass the variable in the query.

Comment: What prevents you from creating the query string on demand? I mean it's just concatenating the strings, or not? If you want to have it more convenient, use [`ParameterizedSparqlString`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) with e.g. `ParameterizedSparqlString q = new ParameterizedSparqlString("select * {?s a base:hotel; ?s rdfs:label ?label}");` and then call `q.setLiteral("label", "something");`

Answer (score 0):

Jena has a set of classes useful to build a query instance. 
Here is an example that builds a query like yours:

```
String yourclassuri =  "base:hotel" ;
    //Intialize the select statatment
    Query select = new Query();

    //set prefixes
    select.setPrefix("rdf","rdfurl");
    select.setPrefix("base","yourbaseurl");

    select.setQuerySelectType();
    select.addResultVar("s");
    select.addResultVar("p");
    select.addResultVar("o");

    final ElementPathBlock elementPathBlock = new ElementPathBlock();

    //create the first pattern in the where
    final Node s = NodeFactory.createVariable("s");
    final Node p = NodeFactory.createVariable("p");
    final Node o = NodeFactory.createVariable("o");
    elementPathBlock.addTriple(new Triple(s,p,o));

    //create the last pattern
    final Node subclass = NodeFactory.createURI("rdf:subClassOf");
    final Node rdfclass = NodeFactory.createURI(yourclassuri);
    elementPathBlock.addTriple(new Triple(s,subclass,rdfclass));

    select.setQueryPattern(elementPathBlock);

    //serialize the query in a string
    String query = select.serialize();

    //output select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o. ?s rdf:subClassOf base:hotel}
```

Sources: [Jena javadoc](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/overview-summary.html)

Notice that you can use a [ParametrizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) but it seems ineffective when you want to inject prefixed names (like *base:name*). The Javadoc also warns about possible SPARQL inject problems:

> SPARQL Injection Notes
>
> While this class was in part designed to prevent SPARQL injection it is by no means foolproof because it works purely at the textual level. The current version of the code addresses some possible attack vectors that the developers have identified but we do not claim to be sufficiently devious to have thought of and prevented every possible attack vector.

I suspect that query building is a bit more safer against this kind of attacks.
Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43020661/925955) it is an other aswer about the limits of ParameterizedSparqlString.

Comment: well, I don't think is what she was asking for (besides that the question is not rellz clear to me). from my point of view, is much simpler to use just a Java String. And if something like a template query is needed, [`ParameterizedSparqlString`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) is the way to go.

Comment: based on her last comment I was thinking about a parametrized query... Anyway I didn't know about ParameterizedSparqlString. I agree that in this case it fits better, then build the entire query. I'll update the answer with your suggestion! Thank you.

Comment: I've found that there's no method to effectively inject a prefixed name in a query template using ParametrizeSparqlString. `setIri("var","name:value")` method inject `<name:value>` which is not a valid SPARQL GraphNode. See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43020661/925955 for further details.

Comment: String sparql = "SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE { ?s rdfs:subClassOf ?object.}";

ParameterizedSparqlString queryStr = new ParameterizedSparqlString(sparql);
String value = "http://www.something.org/ontology#Feature";
queryStr.setIri("object", value);

It is showing all the classes with the property rdfs:subClassOf. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the parameter is actually substituted? Other than that I've no clue, sorry. Have you tried the query builder approach?